# Improve or optimize a very slow query

Tags: database, query-posts, performance

I have a fairly large database - 113,299 rows in wp_posts and 216,0649 rows in wp_postmeta.

There is one custom query that I run after a post is added or edited, which appears in MySQL's slow-log file every time it runs -- and seems to take way too many seconds (between 17 to 78 seconds, in fact).

This is what it looks like in `query_posts`:

```
    $args = array( 
                'meta_query' => array(
                                    array(
                                        'key' => 'article_template',
                                        'value' => 'news',
                                    ),
                                ),
                'posts_per_page' => '30',
                'category__in' => array( 3, 4, 5 ),
                'post_status' => 'publish',
                'no_found_rows' => true,
                'orderby' => 'meta_value',
                'meta_key' => 'article_datetime',
                'order' => 'DESC'
            );
    query_posts( $args );
```

And this is what it looks like in MySQL's slow-log file:

```
SELECT   wp_posts.ID FROM wp_posts  INNER JOIN wp_term_relationships ON (wp_posts.ID = wp_term_relationships.object_id) INNER JOIN wp_postmeta ON (wp_posts.ID = wp_postmeta.post_id)
INNER JOIN wp_postmeta AS mt1 ON (wp_posts.ID = mt1.post_id) WHERE 1=1  AND ( wp_term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id IN (3,4,5) ) AND wp_posts.post_type = 'post' AND (wp_posts.post_status = 'publish') AND (wp_postmeta.meta_key = 'article_datetime'
AND  (mt1.meta_key = 'article_template' AND CAST(mt1.meta_value AS CHAR) = 'news') ) GROUP BY wp_posts.ID ORDER BY wp_postmeta.meta_value DESC LIMIT 0, 30;
```

This is what EXPLAIN shows for this query:

```
mysql> explain SELECT   wp_posts.ID FROM wp_posts  INNER JOIN wp_term_relationships ON (wp_posts.ID = wp_term_relationships.object_id) INNER JOIN wp_postmeta ON (wp_posts.ID = wp_postmeta.post_id)
    -> INNER JOIN wp_postmeta AS mt1 ON (wp_posts.ID = mt1.post_id) WHERE 1=1  AND ( wp_term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id IN (3,4,5) ) AND wp_posts.post_type = 'post' AND (wp_posts.post_status = 'publish') AND (wp_postmeta.meta_key = 'article_datetime' AND  (mt1.meta_key = 'article_template' AND CAST(mt1.meta_value AS CHAR) = 'news') ) GROUP BY wp_posts.ID ORDER BY wp_postmeta.meta_value DESC LIMIT 0, 30;
+----+-------------+-----------------------+--------+--------------------------+----------+---------+-----------------------------+-------+----------------------------------------------+
| id | select_type | table                 | type   | possible_keys            | key      | key_len | ref                         | rows  | Extra                                        |
+----+-------------+-----------------------+--------+--------------------------+----------+---------+-----------------------------+-------+----------------------------------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | wp_postmeta           | ref    | post_id,meta_key         | meta_key | 768     | const                       | 98576 | Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | wp_posts              | eq_ref | PRIMARY,type_status_date | PRIMARY  | 8       | toi_web.wp_postmeta.post_id |     1 | Using where                                  |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | mt1                   | ref    | post_id,meta_key         | post_id  | 8       | toi_web.wp_postmeta.post_id |    11 | Using where                                  |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | wp_term_relationships | ref    | PRIMARY,term_taxonomy_id | PRIMARY  | 8       | toi_web.mt1.post_id         |     2 | Using where; Using index                     |
+----+-------------+-----------------------+--------+--------------------------+----------+---------+-----------------------------+-------+----------------------------------------------+
```

So I'm wondering if anyone has a good tip or suggestion how to optimize this and avoid the slow query? Maybe break this into a different `query_posts` loop? Or first grab the posts' IDs with a simple `wpdb->get_results` query?

I'm open to any suggestions :)

*By the way, we have a very robust MySQL cluster, so server resources is not the issue*.

Comment: You should never use `query_posts`, use `pre_get_posts` or `WP_Query` instead

Comment: It is almost certainly the `'orderby' => 'meta_value',`. You may find it quicker to sort your posts in PHP.

Comment: Apologies for my ignorance, Tom, but does it affect the query speed? Using the exact same $args, WP_Query doesn't generate a different MySQL query than query_posts so therefore the query will still be slow. And why not use query_posts when this is a completely custom query? It's not running inside a loop, and it's not hooking into an existing wordpress query. So why is query_posts forbidden? Thanks for the answer and for your help.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, s_ha_dum. I will give it a try and compare times!

Comment: No really. Use pre_get_posts. Read the opening note on query_posts. http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/query_posts

Comment: @BiranitGoren This [thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26319613/improving-a-query-using-a-lot-of-inner-joins-to-a-key-value-table) might be of interest to you.

Comment: @RyanLoremIpsum, but I'm not modifying the main query -- this is part of a custom function. It runs on save_post and the resulting loop writes the the whole html thing into a static file, which I then include in a sidebar module. So I don't see how pre_get_post can be used here.

Comment: Can you create a new WP_query instead? `$custom_query = new WP_Query( $args );` See the caveats for query_posts http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/query_posts#Secondary_Loops

Comment: @RyanLoremIpsum, yes I can - and tried it. But the end result is the same, since it creates the same MySQL. I think the only viable way for me will be to try and avoid using wp_postmeta in the same query - so probably use a simple MySQL query to grab the relevant post IDs and then run them into a WP_Query loop...

Comment: Depending on your server configuration, setting `'cache_results' => false` may improve performance. 
http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Caching_Parameters

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Persuming "article_datetime" to be a numeric value, I would suggest that instead of using 'orderby' => 'meta_value' use **'orderby' => 'meta_value_num'**
2. If still query is slow, than remove:

   'orderby' => 'meta_value',
   'meta_key' => 'article_datetime',
   'order' => 'DESC'

and instead sort the result in php.